# rock64 strange video modes

Tags: debian, xorg, xrandr

I've had a [Rock64](https://www.pine64.org/?page_id=7147) for a couple months.  Tried running an Ayufan (Debian) image, then tried an Armbian one, now I'm back to the latest Ayufan.  I boot it up, it doesn't read my *EDID* on my old monitor, I end up in *1920x1080* mode.  No big surprise.  But I can't find a good manual override.  I want *1366x768*.

I try `xrandr`, it says I'm in *1920x1080*, won't let me change it.  `fbset` gives me:

```
FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO: Invalid argument
```

even when I try to set a mode that was shipped in /etc/fb.modes like *1024x768-60*.  `xvidtune` doesn't let me change anything.  This is affecting both console and X(org).

What I stumbled onto is `lxrandr` partly because it's a little box I can drag around the screen and pick a mode from a GUI list.  What surprises me is that it works (for X).  I don't know why.  I can pick *1024x768* and that's what I get.  But `xrandr` (not `lxrandr`) says I'm still in *1920x1080*.  Switched my monitor to the TV input for half an hour, when I came back it really had switched to *1920x1080*.  Reboot, bring up X, and that's at *1024x768*.  `lxrandr` (I stuck it in my `xinit`) now says *1920x1080*.  Switch to *1024x768*, only the numbers change because that's what I was already at anyway.

`ls /dev/fb*` shows only *fb0*.  `lsof` doesn't find it open.  There's a */dev/mali*, that's not open either.  From what I can find in Mali documentation, the system creates the framebuffer, the Mali just writes into it.  It's likely to have been set up as part of the boot process, but why can `lxrandr`, (and only `lxrandr` so far) change it?  Or does it make another framebuffer it can manipulate, which maybe goes away when the screen blanks?

Is there someplace I can set the video/framebuffer mode for both console and X and have it stay?

Comment: Framebuffer mode has not so many modes available is not as flexible as other modes.

Comment: What other modes?  There may be some DRI but it seems like both console and X share a framebuffer (same physical size - not full screen).  Ctrl-Alt-F2(-4) does work for virtual terminals, but they're all the same size.  Seems like I should be able to use framebuffer modes from /etc/fb.modes, if not add more.  But maybe it's not  a framebuffer at all.

Comment: Another wacky thing is that if I try to do Xorg -configure it fails claiming it can't find a monitor.  Meaning it failed to parse the EDID maybe.

Comment: Arm devices are a little ungrateful too. I have dealt for a while fighting with frame buffer configs in an Arm Lamobo R1 in Debian, and in a Lenovo w/ FreeBSD and OpenBSD, but decided it was not worth the trouble and the inflexibility. ´

Comment: I can do an fbset -g to specify geometry.  Look at fbset output and it shows the mode I just set.  But that's not what the screen does.  There is only one /dev/fb* but I suppose there could be one somewhere else called something else.  It's conventional to call them /dev/fb* but not obilgitory.  Wonder what a serial console will show when my adapter comes.  I'm guessing the framebuffer I see is set up at boot, maybe an argument to the kernel, and the CPU negotiates with the GPU.

Comment: Giving up for now.  It's possible to select modes fom the kernel command line I think, but only for modes that have been implemented by some lower level process.  My /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes lists only 1920x1080 and that's the only thing I've made work.  Except lxrandr (with LXDE) gets me other working modes, but only in X.  It may set up a substitute framebuffer, yet the console is still at 1920x1080.  It will do 1024x768 but in the center of the monitor's native 1360x768, the sides are stilll blank.